# Replace multiple characters in a string with one from a generator

Tags: python, algorithm, replace, character, generator

I'm looking for a way to take a string that looks like the following:

```
(a,1),(b,1),(a,1),(b,5),(a,1),(b,2),(a,1),(b,1),(a,2),(b,6),(a,2)
```

And replace the first "a" with an even number, the second with the next
up even number, and so on for however long the string is. Then I'd like to take the first "b" and assign it an odd number, then the next "b" gets the
next highest odd number, and so on for however long the string is. I'm
working primarily in Python 2.7, but would be willing to look into other languages if a solution exists in that.

Comment: So what is the problem? You can parse the string, keep count of a's and b's and for every p^th a, assign it to 2*p and for every q^th b, assign it to (2*q-1)

Comment: Next time, please show us some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: You really don't need any background for this. I wanted to take a string in the above format, and simply modify it using python code. Martin did that beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression substitution should work:

```
import re

def odd_even(x):
    global a,b
    if x.group(1) == 'a':
        a += 2
        return str(a)
    else:
        b += 2
        return str(b)

a = 0
b = -1
source = "(a,1),(b,1),(a,1),(b,5),(a,1),(b,2),(a,1),(b,1),(a,2),(b,6),(a,2)"

print re.sub("([ab])", odd_even, source)
```

This prints:

```
(2,1),(1,1),(4,1),(3,5),(6,1),(5,2),(8,1),(7,1),(10,2),(9,6),(12,2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry for not posting more background data, I did this late last night. If we switched the group numbers, would it work the other way?

if x.group(1) == 'b':
        b += 2
        return str(b)
    else:
        a += 2
        return str(a)

Comment: I'm getting the error 
name 're' not defined is a code error, or could it be caused by the fact that I am using Visual Studio (2015)

Comment: Forget that, I fixed it

Comment: Sorry about tha, I had left out the import

Answer (score 0):

```
even = 2
while "a" in string:
    string = string.replace("a", str(even), 1)
    even += 2

odd = 1
while "b" in string:
    string = string.replace("b", str(odd), 1)
    odd += 2
```